# How can I update a post in yammer?

Tags: yammer

I know how to create, delete, and get a message, but I could not work out how to update an existing post.

Comment: According to Yammer's Director of UX this is [under active development](https://yammer.uservoice.com/forums/399627-yammer/suggestions/15612063-support-editing-of-yammer-posts)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 'update' is equivalent to 'edit', Yammer doesn't allow for this capability. You are only able to create, delete and get messages.

Comment: So how remove the entire hashtag from a post?

if i create a hashtag in the post body, them became a hashtag and a topic, 
I know how to remove a topic, but this hashtag still in my postbody

Thanks!